# How to insert an object into another object within an array in mongo

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express, javascript-objects

I have a mongo db where I have create a record that has an object within an array (e.g. employees: [{name:Bob, Age: 30}]. I now want to update the object within the array so it looks like [{name:Bob, age: 30, pay:400}]. How do I do this within a node/express route? If I use something like:

```
router.put("/addPay/:id",function(req,res){
Team.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{$push:{employee: {$each: 
[{pay:req.body.pay}]}}},........
```

this just pushes {pay: XXX} as a separate object into the array [{name:Bob, age: 30, pay:400}, {pay: XXX}] rather than inserting it  into the object already there. I know there are plenty of questions about pushing into objects and arrays etc on SO but I couldn't find a similar example to this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Does `req.body` contain employee's name ?

Comment: No its the pay amount (e.g. 400). If I console.log it, I get the value passed through from my form so that works...

Comment: So how do you know which employee should have this value set ? Do you have always one value in that array ?

Comment: yes exactly - just the one employee. The model Schema I am using is actualluy more complicated than this - i just made this to get the heart of my problem.

Comment: Okay, then the answer provided by @cowCrazy should be fine for you, just use `employee.0.pay`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the index of the object you want to change, then you write it like this:

`'array.index.keyToUpdate'`.

If you have the index of the object before the update operation you can do it like this:

`{$set: { 'employee.<indexToChange>.pay': 400 }}`.

To make it dynamic and based on the query you can do:

`update({ 'employee.name': 'Bob' }, {$set: { 'employee.$.pay': 400 }})`.

In this case the `$` stands for the first matched object in the array.